# Cordova cdvfile url for images doesn't work on ios

Tags: cordova, cordova-ios

Can someone please point out what I am missing and why the same url that works on the android version of the app doesn't work for ios. I am geting all the text data from the same path but couldn't be able to display the images, here is the error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

cdvfile://localhost/persistent/appName/.images/folderName/imageName.png

Answer (score 1):

The url should look like this:

```
cdvfile://localhost/persistent/directory/image.png
```

directory: The name of the directory, **which you created inside your app**. Maybe that is appName in your code.

For more informations about files and directories, see here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file

Maybe that your error comes from the dot before «images».

Comment: nope, thats not it, All the images are placed inside that directory and I have used the same path for android and it works. I am wondering if its possible to get the exact path of directories in ios by console.log or by any means just like the android console support in chrome , because the safari iOS simulator console starts outputting console logs after the app starts and it doesn't do much